# solvability of $r^x \equiv a \pmod {n}$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

$r^x \equiv  a \pmod {n}$
Is it correct to say this congruence is solvable if and only if $\gcd(a,n) = 1$ ?  I am looking for a proof or intuitive argument for making sense of this. Thanks in advance!
(r is a primitive root of n)

Comment: please see below link for more details on source of this question http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1109386/why-are-there-no-solutions-to-2x-equiv-3-pmod9

Comment: I think I can see one direction from previous question : the congruence is not solvable when $\gcd(a,n) \ne 1$. But I'm not sure if this is always solvable when $\gcd(a,n) = 1$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $r$ is primitive root of $n$ then $r$ is a generator of cyclic multiplicative group $\mathbb{Z}_n^{\star}$, which is the set of all $a$ with $\gcd(a,n)=1$.

So if $\gcd(a,n)=1$ then $a \in \mathbb{Z}_n^{\star},\,$ i.e. there is an $x$ with $r^x\equiv a \bmod n$. If $\gcd(a,n)\ne 1$ then $a \not \in \mathbb{Z}_n^{\star}$ and there cannot be such $x.$